# Python - package does not work in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, package

I'm trying to create a package and I'm following the tutorial [here](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/). The code works fine when using the native Python installed on my Mac but when I activated the virtualenv, it doesn't work. Could you please tell me why and how can I make this work? Thanks!

```
# python -V
Python 2.7.10
# source env/bin/activate
(env) # python -V
Python 3.6.0
(env) # python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Animals import Mammals
  File "/private/tmp/test/Animals/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Mammals import Mammals
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Mammals'
(env) # deactivate
# python -V
Python 2.7.10
# python test.py
Printing members of the Mammals class
    Tiger
    Elephant
    Wild Cat
Printing members of the Birds class
    Sparrow
    Robin
    Duck
# ls -lrtah
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 btm   wheel   324B Feb 12 02:29 test.py
drwxr-xr-x  5 btm   wheel   170B Feb 12 02:32 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 btm   wheel   238B Feb 12 02:32 env
drwxr-xr-x  9 btm   wheel   306B Feb 12 02:38 Animals
drwxrwxrwt  9 root  wheel   306B Feb 12 02:44 ..
# tree Animals
Animals
├── Birds.py
├── Birds.pyc
├── Mammals.py
├── Mammals.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
└── __pycache__
    └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc

# cat Animals/__init__.py
from Mammals import Mammals
from Birds import Birds
# virtualenv --version
15.0.3
```

Comment: use `from .Mammals import Mammals` in Animals/__init__.py

Comment: Thanks @ThmeiEsi! That works! I can just add "." for testing purposes like when in virtualenv, but if I'm going to build my app, I can just use the existing code without ".", correct?

Comment: Not sure, I don't think there is any reason to remove the '.', maybe just leave them in?

Comment: Copy that @ThmeiEsi! But I'm still wondering why it works without the "." when the virtualenv is not active.

Comment: Python imports depend on the current working directory when the program is run. All import paths need to take the working directory into account or use a relative import path. The '.' tells python to use a relative import path and to start searching for modules in the same directory as the current file being run.

Comment: I'm running it indirectly, via `python test.py`.

Comment: Ok. So in that case the working directory is the directory where test.py exists. So all import statements executed in that context will start looking for modules in the same directory as test.py. -- Even if the actual import happens in a different directory (what is happening in Animals/__init__.py) So, basically python checks for a file called Mammals.py and can't find it because it is not looking in the correct place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135466/discussion-between-thmei-esi-and-sedawkgrep).

Comment: Makes sense now! Thanks for your help @ThmeiEsi! :)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.